# Number of seconds in year changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, math, time

I have written this function to convert inputted seconds into an output for a user that is in Years, Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds. I am still working on the various outputs and I know their is a better way to syntax this; however, for now I am looking for a calculation error I get when conversions get into years. I am a few minutes off, can anybody spot this error? I appreciate it. Also if you have suggestions on my formatting, I would really appreciate it. I was considering a switch statement, but wasn't sure what to use as a input condition.

**Please debug with the function input => formatDuration(69771311);**

```
function formatDuration(n) {

  var arr=[~~(n/31536000 ),~~(n%31536000 /86400)%365,~~(n%31536000%86400/3600)%24,~~(n%31536000 %86400%3600/60)%60,n%31536000 %86400%3600%60%60];
    console.log(arr);


 if(arr[4] <= 0 && arr[1] == 0 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[3] == 0)
    return 'now';
 //Single Second        
 else if( arr[4] == 1 && arr[1] == 0 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[3] == 0 && arr[0] == 0 )
        return arr[4]+' second';
//Single minute, multiple seconds       
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] == 1 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[3]+' minute and '+arr[4]+' seconds';
 //Multiple Seconds         
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[1] == 0 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[3] == 0 )
        return arr[4]+' seconds'; 
 //Single Minute
 else if(arr[4] == 0 && arr[3] == 1 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[3]+' minute';
 //Multiple Minutes
 else if(arr[4] == 0 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[3]+' minutes';
 //Single Second and Single Minute
 else if(arr[4] == 1 && arr[3] == 1 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[3]+' minute and ' + arr[4] + ' second';
 //Multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if(arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[3]+' minutes and ' + arr[4] + ' seconds';   
 //Multiple minutes and single seconds
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[3]+' minutes and ' + arr[4] + ' seconds';  
 //Single hour, multiple minutes, and single second 
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[2]+' hour, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and '+arr[4]+' seconds';   
 //Single hour, single minute
 else if( arr[4] == 0 && arr[3] == 1 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[2]+' hour and ' + arr[3] + ' minute';  
 //Single hour and single minute 
 else if( arr[4] == 1 && arr[3] == 1 && arr[2] == 0 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[2]+' hour and' + arr[3] + ' minute';  
 //Single hour, single minute and single second
 else if( arr[4] == 1 && arr[3] == 1 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[2]+' hour,  ' + arr[3] + ' minute and ' +arr[4]+ ' second';
 //Single hour and single second
 else if( arr[4] == 1 && arr[3] == 0 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[2]+' hour and ' +arr[4]+ ' second '; 
//single hour
 else if( arr[4] == 0 && arr[3] == 0 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[2]+' hour';
//Single hour, single minute and multiple second
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] == 1 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] == 0 )
        return arr[2]+' hour, ' + arr[3] + ' minute and ' +arr[4]+ ' seconds';  
//Multiple days, single hour, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[0] == 0 )
        return arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hour, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and ' +arr[4]+ ' seconds';
//Single day, single hour, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] > 0 && arr[0] == 0 )
        return arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hour, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and ' +arr[4]+ ' seconds';
//multiple days, multiple hours, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] > 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[0] == 0 )
        return arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hours, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and ' +arr[4]+ ' seconds';
//Multiple years, multiple days, single hour, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[0] > 0 )
        return arr[0]+' years, ' + arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hour, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and ' +arr[4]+ ' seconds'; 
//single years, multiple days, single hour, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] == 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[0] == 1 )
        return arr[0] + ' year, ' +arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hour, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and ' +arr[4]+ ' seconds';        
//single years, multiple days, multiple hour, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] > 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[0] == 1 )
        return arr[0] + ' year, ' +arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hours, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and ' +arr[4]+ ' seconds';       
//multiple years, multiple days, multiple hours, multiple minutes 0 seconds
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] > 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[0] == 0 )
        return arr[0] + ' years, ' +arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hours, and ' + arr[3] + ' minutes';   
//multiple years, multiple days, multiple hours, multiple minutes nd single second
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] > 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[0] == 1 )
        return arr[0] + ' years, ' +arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hours, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and ' + arr[4]+' second';   
    //multiple years, multiple days, multiple hours, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[4] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[2] > 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[0] > 1 )
        return arr[0] + ' years, ' +arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hours, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and '+arr[4] + ' seconds';  
 //multiple years, multiple days, multiple hours, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[0] > 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[2] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[4] == 0 )
        return arr[0] + ' years, ' +arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hours and ' + arr[3] + ' minutes';  
 //multiple years, multiple days, multiple hours, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[0] > 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[2] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[4] == 1 )
        return arr[0] + ' years, ' +arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hours, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and ' + arr[4] + ' second';  
//multiple years, multiple days, multiple hours, multiple minutes and multiple seconds
 else if( arr[0] > 1 && arr[1] > 1 && arr[2] > 1 && arr[3] > 1 && arr[4] == 1 )
        return arr[0] + ' years, ' +arr[1]+' days, '+arr[2]+' hours, ' + arr[3] + ' minutes and ' + arr[4] + ' second';  
}
```

Comment: Not saying it is wrong or causing the problem, but why isYear==false in the first else block? Better isYear=false? [same question all the way on down with each variable]

Comment: How are you checking? Are you and the checking tool making the same assumption about the number of days in a year?

Comment: Your last two clauses are returning arr[0] seconds instead of arr[4]

Comment: Assuming 365 days in the year as a reference. The switches for the the isYear is basically switching off isYear after the function has completed counting through the number of years based on the input of seconds. Once it is switched off, it is basically just a reference for me. You are right about the operator; however, that isn't the issue.

Comment: When running the function, all is calculated properly until seconds reach years. This is where I am confused as well. I am wondering if I should be passing ' a ' which I have set as my temp input holder as the input for yearConversion or one of my other conversions along with years value. I don't get the wrong number of years, just calculations are off on the rest of the measurements. Not by much, but I am not great with math and was hoping the written conversion functions would do that work for me.

Comment: I am wondering if I need to reverse my order of calculating once isYears is true. Since on a top down approach, seconds is just the left overs of what was calculated through from the top with 'a' as the input.

Comment: Aha, thank you for spotting that. However, my console.logging of the array holding the values still doesn't match up even though you are correct about the return statement.

Comment: At 365 days per year, times 86400 seconds per day, you get 31536000 not 31556926.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got it right you might do this job as follows;

```js
var formatDuration = n => [~~(n/31536000),~~(n%31536000/86400)%365,~~(n%31536000%86400/3600)%24,~~(n%31536000%86400%3600/60)%60,n%31536000%86400%3600%60%60];
console.log(formatDuration(69771311));
```

Where returned array's

```
index 0: # of years,
index 1: # of days,
index 2: # of hours,
index 3: # of minutes,
index 4: # of seconds,
```

Comment: This is a good format, quick. But, my question is, why won't dreamweaver recognize this format? Should I use another ide and install a newer version of js?

Comment: The test inputs are automated through a testing program. So, an input needs to be available for the program.

Comment: I got that to work for 7 different tests with a change in days to 86400.

Comment: Still though, even with the last array element either at %60%60 or just %60 I get errors. _Expected: '4 years, 68 days, 3 hours and 4 minutes', instead got: '4 years, 67 days, 3 hours, 48 minutes and 4 seconds'_

Comment: @O'jan G I am using JavaScript ES6 arrow functions here. Dreamweaver might not recognize ES6 by default; may be you need to enable through some menus. You might try Atom too... for JS and Node it is very convenient.

Comment: @O'jan G The way i crosscheck is counting back the seconds from the array results. It should sum up to the figure initially passed to the function.

Comment: @Redu you have 86300 where you mean (I think) 86400.

Comment: @Jeremy Kahan - 86400 is right and I appreciate the time to help. I am going to reconfigure considering I didn't take into account the number of seconds in 365 days and went by a labeled number online.

Comment: @Jeremy Kahan yes thank you i must have overlooked.. Now it all seems fine and crosscheck (summing up the seconds give 69771311) is also fine.